# Testing order using a hashmap

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I'm a ruby beginner and reading that a Hash does not have order. I tried to play with that concept but found I could still order things like so:

```
Travel_Plans = Hash.new
Travel_Plans[4] = "Colorado Springs"
Travel_Plans[1] = "Santa Fe"
Travel_Plans[2] = "Raton"
Travel_Plans[5] = "Denver"
Travel_Plans[3] = "Pueblo"

puts Travel_Plans.sort
```

Could someone explain what is meant by "Hash does not have order"?

If you could provide a simple example that would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby's `Hash` class represents a "hash map" or "key-value dictionary" in conventional terms. These are intended to be structures that allow quick random-access to individual elements, but the elements themselves have no intrinsic ordering.

Internally Ruby's `Hash` organizes elements into their various locations in memory using the `hash` method each object must provide to be used as a key. Ruby's `Hash` is unusually, if not ludicrously flexible, in that an object, any object, can be used as a key, and it's preserved exactly as-is. Contrast with JavaScript where keys *must* be strings and strings only.

That means you can do this:

```
{ 1 => 'Number One', '1' => 'String One', :one => 'Symbol One', 1.0 => 'Float One }
```

Where that has four completely different keys.

This is in contrast to `Array` where the ordering is an important part of how an array works. You don't want to have a queue where things go in one order and come out in another.

Now Ruby's `Hash` class used to have no intrinsic order, but due to popular demand now it stores order in terms of insertion. That is, the first items inserted are "first". Normally you don't depend on this behaviour explicitly, but it does show up if you're paying attention:

```
a = { x: '1', y: '2' }
# => {:x=>"1, :y=>"2"}

b = { }
b[:y] = '2'
b[:x] = '1'
b
# => {:y=>"2", :x=>"1"}
```

Note that the order of the keys in `b` are reversed due to inserting them in reverse order. They're still equivalent though:

```
a == b
# => true
```

When you call `sort` on a `Hash` you actually end up converting it to an array of key/value pairs, then sorting each of those:

```
b.sort
# => [[:x, "1"], [:y, "2"]]
```

Which you could convert back into a `Hash` if you want:

```
b.sort.to_h
# => {:x=>"1", :y=>"2"}
```

So now it's "ordered" properly. In practice this rarely matters, though, as you'll be accessing the keys individually as necessary. `b[:x]` doesn't care where the `:x` key is, it always returns the right value regardless.

Some things to note about Ruby:

- Don't use `Hash.new`, instead just use `{ }` to represent an empty Hash structure.
- Don't use capital letters for variables, they have significant meaning in Ruby.  `Travel_Plans` is a constant, not a variable, because it starts with a capital letter. Those are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` type usage. This should be `travel_plans`.

Comment: Great answer!  But why is `{ }` preferred over `Hash.new` ?

Comment: It's less verbose, which is generally the direction Ruby code steers, plus maps to other languages like JavaScript where that notation is identical. You use `Hash.new` for special cases like `Hash.new(0)` or `Hash.new { |h,k| ... }` where you need to customize the behaviour.

Comment: Very nice explanation. A quibble: perhaps "equal" rather than "equivalent". Consider mentioning `h[k]` when hash `h` has no key `k`, `fetch` and defaults (as long as you've gone this far).

Comment: @CarySwoveland It depends on your meaning of "equal". The contents of the hashes are equal, but the objects themselves aren't. `a.equal? b #=> false` When converted to an array they also wouldn't be considered equal. `a.to_a == b.to_a #=> false` In my opinion "equivalent" is a better fit, but in hash context "equal" also works.

Comment: I have to agree equivalent is the correct term here they are not necessarily equal  but they are equivalent as in can be compared in such a fashion as to represent equality when viewed in an isolated context. Especially given the fact that this question is about ordering and their order is certainly not equal as noted but they are equivalent in that their key => value associations are the same in an order ignorant fashion. Maybe you could say they are `eql?` :)

Comment: @engineersmnky Here I'm using "are equivalent" as in contrast to "are identical". They contain identical data, but the order is different. What's odd is they're also `===`-quivalent too. Is that "eequivalent"?

Comment: @JohanWentholt, that's a good point. I considered the different "equals" but am now unhappy with my suggested wording. I don't like "equivalent" or "equal". Rather, I think the sentence should be reworded.

Comment: @tadman Also, for an empty hash, literal notation `{}` will do `newhash 0`; `Hash.new` will generate `opt_send_without_block` method call to `hash_from_ary`. The former is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

First, the statement "[h]ash does not have order" is wrong as of today. It used to be true for really old and outdated versions of Ruby. You seem to have picked outdated information, which would be unreliable as of today.

Second, the code you provided:

```
puts Travel_Plans.sort
```

is irrelevant to showing your point that the hash `Travel_Plans` has, i.e. preserves, the order. What you should have done to check whether the order is preserved, is to simply do:

```
p Travel_Plans
```

which would always result in showing the keys in the order `4`, `1`, `2`, `5`, `3`, which matches the order in which you assigned the key-values to the hash, thus indeed shows that hash preserves the order.